# Use of undeclared type Xcode 11

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data

Use of undeclared type

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox
// import AVFoundation
import GameKit
import StoreKit
import CoreData
import UnityAds
import CloudKit

var tasks: [MoneyCoredata] = []
```

I don't understand how to declare MoneyCoredata in Xcode 11. The error is:

> Use of undeclared type 'MoneyCoredata'

Before updating I didn't have any problem.

Comment: Where did you expect the type 'MoneyCoredata' to be declared?

Comment: Before updating what?

Comment: MoneyCoreData doesn't seem to be a very descriptive name for a Type...  what are you trying to accomplish?   I see a lot of stuff imported in this code.. How is your question related to AudioToolBox, GameKit, StoreKit, UnityAdds, etc?